# Send a email in Outlook for automation

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32, win32com, office-automation

Tried to send an outlook email as a part of automation. But the usual code seems not working. Not sure what I'm missing here.

The code I tried is here

```
import win32com.client
ol=win32com.client.Dispatch("outlook.application")
olmailitem=0x0 #size of the new email
newmail=ol.CreateItem(olmailitem)
```

The error I'm facing here is

[image]

Deleted the files under AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.9 But still got the error.
[image]

Comment: Do you get the same error with the `Items.Add` method?

Comment: Change olmailitem to 0

Comment: @0m3r The `0x0` doesn't seem to stop the code working for me, at least. I'd suggest deleting all the file and folders under `..\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.9` and re-trying, as perhaps something is going wrong with the python wrapper files.

Comment: @DS_London, Deleted the files under 3.9, but still getting the error. Updated the picture in the question

Comment: if you remove `olmailitem=0x0 `?

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model provides two main ways for creating new items:

1. The [Items.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.add) creates a new Outlook item in the `Items` collection for the folder.
2. The [Application.CreateItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.createitem) method creates and returns a new Microsoft Outlook item.

You can read more about these methods in the [How to create and show a new Outlook mail item programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/26/outlook-create-show-message-programmatically/) article.

---

Be aware, sometimes you need to use the [NameSpace.Logon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.logon) method which logs the user on to MAPI, obtaining a MAPI session.

Use the Logon method only to log on to a specific profile when Outlook is not already running. This is because only one Outlook process can run at a time, and that Outlook process uses only one profile and supports only one MAPI session. When users start Outlook a second time, that instance of Outlook runs within the same Outlook process, does not create a new process, and uses the same profile.

If Outlook is already running, using this method does not create a new Outlook session or change the current profile to a different one.

If Outlook is not running and you only want to start Outlook with the default profile, don't use the `Logon` method. A better alternative is shown in the following code example, `InitializeMAPI`: first, instantiate the Outlook Application object, then reference a default folder such as the Inbox. This has the side effect of initializing MAPI to use the default profile and to make the object model fully functional. For example, VBA sample follows:

```
Sub InitializeMAPI ()

    ' Start Outlook.
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    ' Get a session object. 
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    ' Create an instance of the Inbox folder. 
    ' If Outlook is not already running, this has the side
    ' effect of initializing MAPI.
    Dim mailFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Set mailFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    ' Continue to use the object model to automate Outlook.
End Sub
```

When the MAPI is initialized you can create a new Outlook item.

Answer (score 0):

The same code works now.

Previously the outlook application was open in my pc and when I run the code, it was not working. But now I just closed the application and it works well now.

Not sure whether it is the solution. but somehow it fixed the issue.

Code:

```
import win32com.client
ol=win32com.client.Dispatch("outlook.application")
olmailitem=0x0 #size of the new email
newmail=ol.CreateItem(olmailitem)
```